# Why am I getting an initialization error when using python-pkcs11?

Tags: python, pkcs#11, hsm

In the past I was able to successfully use the python-pkcs11 package to perform cryptographic operations with a Thales netHsm. I'm using Python 3.7 and I have an environment variable called PKCS11_MODULE that points to the location of my pkcs11 library (in this case, it's cknfast-32.dll, a pkcs11 library provided by nCipher). However, now when I run:

```
import pkcs11
import os
lib = pkcs11.lib(os.environ['PKCS11_MODULE'])
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkcs11\_errors.pyx", line 88, in pkcs11._pkcs11.assertRV
RuntimeError: Initialisation error (not initialized). Should never see this.
Exception ignored in: 'pkcs11._pkcs11.lib.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkcs11\_errors.pyx", line 88, in pkcs11._pkcs11.assertRV
RuntimeError: Initialisation error (not initialized). Should never see this.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\python_pkcs11-0.5.1.dev35+g7f4427d-py3.7-win32.egg\pkcs11\__init__.py", line 32, in lib
    _lib = _pkcs11.lib(so)
  File "pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx", line 1245, in pkcs11._pkcs11.lib.__cinit__
  File "pkcs11\_errors.pyx", line 88, in pkcs11._pkcs11.assertRV
pkcs11.exceptions.FunctionFailed
```

It seems that python-pkcs11 is no longer able to load my pkcs11 library. Please advise if you have a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that call to `C_Initialize` gives `CKR_CRYPTOKI_NOT_INITIALIZED` (see python-pkcs11 sources [here](https://github.com/danni/python-pkcs11/blob/v0.6.0/pkcs11/_pkcs11.pyx#L1245) and [here](https://github.com/danni/python-pkcs11/blob/v0.6.0/pkcs11/_errors.pyx#L15)). Is HSM working properly (does `enquiry` utility list it as operational)? Does any other middleware you have work with the token?

Comment: @vlp Thanks for your input, it turns out there was a problem with the state of my security world. I'm not sure how it got into a non-usable state but I worked with nCipher to get the security world properly initialized and this fixed the issue.